# Auto generate the CHANGELOG.md file

Tags: java, angular, changelog

I generated the CHANGELOG.md file in angular project by using generate-changelog Npm package. but the problem is I have to manually type the command and update the CHANGLOG.md file. How i can automate this process at the time of project build. Other thing is i want to generate that CHANGELOG.md file for both front end (angular) and back end (java) commits. What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: What's the command you are using to generate changelog?

Comment: I used "changelog generate" command

Comment: Just append the command to build script. For eg. If your build script is `ng build`, you can run `ng build && changelog generate`. Update your question with information like how you build front end and backend. Do you use npm commands for front end and maven for backend or something else? This information will help in answering your question concretely.